# Класс при вызове не отображается

Tags: python, python-3.x, yandex-disk

Мой код, убрал часть для экономии места

```
import sys
import yadisk
import os
import pyAesCrypt
from os import stat, remove
import random


class YandexDiskOperations():
    def __init__(self):
        self.get_auth()
        print('yes')

    def get_auth(self):
        self.y = yadisk.YaDisk("94885fad3a5e407b8cda5af348597aae", "59d96c74713947b9bad0f691dffb5699")
        url = self.y.get_code_url()
        with open("data.txt", "rb") as token_txt:
            code = token_txt
            try:
                response = self.y.get_token(code)
                print('no')
            except yadisk.exceptions.BadRequestError:
                sys.exit(1)
            self.y.token = response.access_token
            print('yes')

        if self.y.check_token():
            print("Токен получен")
        else:
            print("Срок жизни токена истек, либо введён не правильно")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('''
    Это приложение работает через код подтверждения.
    Для начала работы перейдите по ссылке:
    https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=94885fad3a5e407b8cda5af348597aae
    После - создайте папку token.txt и вствьте его туда
    ''')
    start = YandexDiskOperations()
```

При вызове программы ничего, кроме принта в `if __name__ == '__main__'` . 
Вопрос, почему?

Comment: Попробуйте поставить принт перед sys.exit(1)

Comment: Да, в этом месте принт работает

Comment: Но даже если токен верный, всё-равно за пределы get_auth не выходит

Comment: И? Вы вызываете код по условию, в котором ровно два действия: 1) напечатать сообщение; 2) сконструировать объект класса `YandexDiskOperations` и присвоить переменной `start`. После этого программа завершается.

Comment: Судя по коду вы выходите из `get_auth()` по исключению. Вот и разбирайтесь, что там не так.